# Using AWS Cloudfront URL singing feature without caching objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to use the URL signing option without caching my content worldwide ?
I host my bucket in Europe, and I would like my data to never be cached overseas.
But I need to keep using signed URLs.

Is it possible to separate the two functionalities, or do I have to use the whole package ?

Answer (score 0):

The two functionalities are separate.  This sounds like a valid use case.

CloudFront has numerous applications that are quite valid where caching is not used, and you can disable caching altogether, if you choose.  This can be done with cache behavior configuration or with `Cache-Control:` headers from your origin server.

However... the question also suggests that you may not have a full understanding of how the CloudFront cache works.  CloudFront doesn't push your content out to the edge location caches.

CloudFront is pull-through, not push-to... and each of the 50+ edge locations' caches are independent, not synchronized.

Content is never cached in an edge location unless that exact object is requested *through* that particular edge location, which normally means that a browser in geographic proximity to that edge submitted an authorized request for that object... so it does not seem like you should have any meaningful concerns with regard to "worldwide" caching.  It doesn't spontaneously happen.

If a request for an object requiring a signed URL is received by an edge location, and the signature is invalid, that particular CloudFront edge does not even fetch the object into its cache, because the signature is validated before CloudFront tries to do anything further.